# Where do i get "GDI_CapturingAnImage.h"? I want GDI_CapturingAnImage.h file

Tags: c++, winapi

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image

GDI_CapturingAnImage.h  header file which is included in GDI_CapturingAnImage.cpp file  . I want to use this file

Answer (score 1):

The code in this page is an example, I don't think you can find the file `GDI_CapturingAnImage.h` online. This file seems to be the header file of the example.

If you want it, you can create it and put the functions declarations inside, like this :

```
//File GDI_CapturingAnImage.h
#ifndef GDI_CAPTURINGANIMAGE_H
#define GDI_CAPTURINGANIMAHE_H

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);

// Put the other declarations here

#endif
```

Comment: _tWinMain not found

Answer (score 1):

The *GDI_CapturingAnImage.h* file referenced in the source is just the header file generated by the New Project wizard in Visual Studio, when you create a regular Windows Desktop application named *GDI_CapturingAnImage*.

The easiest way to get that file is to create a project using the New Project wizard in Visual Studio, and copy the sample contents into the generated .cpp file.

If that's not what you want, you can either manually create the header, and put the appropriate declarations into it, or go without the header altogether, and put those declarations into the .cpp file. The compiler will complain about missing declarations when you compile it.

Answer (score 0):

To try out the code example, begin by creating a new project in Visual Studio based on the Windows Desktop Application project template. It's ***important*** to name the new project GDI_CapturingAnImage so that the code listing below will compile (for example, it includes GDI_CapturingAnImage.h, which will exist in your new project if you name it as suggested).

Open the GDI_CapturingAnImage.cpp source code file in your new project, and replace its contents with the listing below. Then build and run. Each time you resize the window, you'll see the captured screenshot displayed in the client area.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image